# Importing python function gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I created a function and tried importing it into another python script to do some unit tests. However I am constantly getting a `ModuleNotFoundError`. How do I properly import functions form one script to another?

My code:

```py
from src.somefile import some_function

def test_somefunction:
    assert somefunction()
```

The error I encounter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test_file.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src.somefile import convert_epoch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

My folder structure:

```
project/
project/__init__.py
project/src
project/src/__init__.py
project/src/somefile.py
project/test
project/test/__init__.py
project/test/test_file.py
```

I would appreciate if someone could highlight what I am doing wrong and how I can neatly do an import. Thank you!

Comment: yes. i run it in my project directory as 
python test/test_file.py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import modules like that you have to add directory containing your module to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable OR you can use `sys.path`:

```py
import sys
# assumed that /home/you/work contains `project` dir
sys.path.append('/home/you/work')
# now you can import
```

You can also use relative imports (`import ..package`) but they have some constraints (you can go up to a certain point) and are generally speaking a bad practice. Take a look at this article, it describes python's `import` statement in details: https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html

Comment: Thanks. this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work for you, assuming that you're running your script like this
`python test/test_file.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..") # Adds higher directory to python modules path.

from src.somefile import some_function

def test_somefunction:
    assert somefunction()
```